# Can Kundalini energy regress after awakening?

Tags: chakras, kundalini, spiritual-level

In scriptures related to the Kundalini Yoga, it is mentioned that Kundalini, often visualized as a serpent, resides at the base of the spine (Muladhara chakra) and can awaken to ascend through seven chakras:

1. Muladhara
2. Svadhisthana
3. Manipura
4. Anahata
5. Vishuddha
6. Ajna
7. Sahasrara

Under typical circumstances, the Kundalini energy is said to reside dormant at the Muladhara chakra, pointing downwards.

Suppose a practitioner (sadhaka) has awakened their Kundalini and it has ascended to the k-th chakra. My question revolves around the progression or potential regression of this energy.

If the sadhaka ceases spiritual practices and/or engages in actions that are considered negative or harmful, can the Kundalini energy regress to the (k-1)-th chakra or even further downwards? Or is it the case that once awakened, the Kundalini energy only progresses upwards towards the (k+1)-th chakra and beyond?

Comment: Brilliant question!

Comment: Of course, Kundalini would go down. Even the chakras that were opened would close if the aspirant does any unethical thing.

Comment: No. Each time Kundalini moves down each inch, the fear and anxiety would increase and strike upon the practitioner. So, it's not an easy way to reverse Kundalini either. Lower chakras have fear, anxiety, and trauma that won't let you down easily.